# Version check with --version and -version in Java 8 and Java 11

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

**Java 11**

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4
```

I was able to find Java version in cmd with following command:

```
java --version  //successfully executed

java -version  //successfully executed
```

[image]

**Java 8**

```
 JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_231
```

I was able to find Java version in cmd with following command:

```
java -version  //successfully executed
```

while I was unable to find java version with `--version` command

```
java --version  //not successfully executed
```

[image]

Why I get error that Java Virtual Machine could not be created when I execute `--version`, or just  this command option not available in **jdk 8**? If it was added in jdk 11 then where is it mentioned in doc?

Comment: Because classes never start with `-`, while options do. So there’s the simple assumption that everything that starts with `-` is supposed to be an option. But why is that important to you; what actual problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @Holger , it bothers me because I went through jdk 8 and jdk 11 documentation and it was never mentioned that `--version` option support was added in 11. but it do support in 11 while not in 8.

Comment: In Java 8 the `--version` command does not exist, only `-version`. I believe it was Java 9 when the double-dash form was added. This may be part of [JEP 293: Guidelines for JDK Command-Line Tool Options](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/293).

Comment: But you asked an entirely different question. And well, [here it is in the JDK 11 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__GUID-621B6C2B-EDC9-4978-ACA0-ABD8BE193364) whereas it’s not [in the JDK 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI). Case closed.

Comment: Unaffecting, but interestingly there is a significant difference in the note down in [JEP 223: New Version-String Scheme](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223) and [JEP 322: Time-Based Release Versioning](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/322), where the former was a part of Java-9 and the latter of Java-10 with all that discussion around versioning scheme occurring during the launch of Java-9 and later. You can see the examples in the JEP make use of different patterns by themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option was introduced in Java 9.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624), if you search for `--version` it's the first version in which it appears in the `java` tool's documentation (the `java` tool's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for Java 8 doesn't mention it).