# Could not determine java version from '11.0.4'

Tags: java, gradle

I've recently installed gradle-6.0.1 on my computer and downloaded the eclipse plugin. But when I try to create a Gradle Project, eclipse shows this error: Could not determine java version from '11.0.4'. Any ideas on how to fix this?

gradle -version output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+10-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

gradlew --version output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+10-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: Your version of Eclipse is ?

Comment: Eclipse Java 2019-06  version: 4.12.0

Comment: The same error message happens when you use older versions of Gradle with newer versions of Java. I would check one more time that the version you installed is actually the one used by Buildship in Eclipse. Normally, projects use a wrapper that define which version to use.

Comment: add output of `gradle --version` and go to project folder and output of `gradlew --version`

Comment: @dkb Command Prompt doesn't recognize the gradlew --version command. Which project folder are you talking about for that task? Is there a common directory that I could follow to find it?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I installed a plugin from Eclipse Marketplace for gradle support. I also installed gradle on my computer from online.

Comment: Could it be that your project was generated with different gradle version? Is there a `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` script inside your project? If so, what's the ouput of `gradlew --version`

Comment: The Eclipse plugins for gradle that I have are: Gradle IDE Pack 3.8x + 1.0x + 2.2x, Nodeclipse/Enide Gradle for Eclipse 0.17, Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0, and Minimalist Gradle Editor 1.0.1.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki inside which project? I'm sort of new to this whole Gradle thing.

Comment: when you install gradle in your system, `gradle --version` should give response, if you have wrapper inside your project then executing command `gradlew --version` from your project folder should give response.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59152510/version-check-with-version-and-version-in-java-8-and-java-11

Comment: Problem Solved! I entered the gradlew.bat command into Command Prompt it downloaded a zip file and now the project creates in eclipse. Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and change your gradle version to 6.0.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-bin.zip
```